# Using ValueConverter in Style DataTrigger of ItemsControl but List is Empty

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, ivalueconverter, wpf-style

I am attempting to use a ValueConverter to flip the last item in an ItemsControl (so that it appears backwards).

To accomplish this, I created a Style with a DataTrigger which is using a ValueConverter to check if the current item is the last item in the list.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:FIsLastItemInContainerConverter x:Key="IsLastItemInContainerConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveAction.ActionIconDatas}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="local:FActionInfoControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 0.5"/>
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <ContentControl>
          <local:FActionInfoControl/>
        </ContentControl>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The issue appears to be with my ValueConverter.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;

    // THIS IS RETURNING NULL
    ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

    if (ic == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) == ic.Items.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

Although `item` is a valid element in the `ItemsControl`, the call to `ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer` is returning null and I'm not sure why. It is being set, and displays fine (it just is never flipped as the style should cause it to).

Any ideas on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your binding with:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}, AncestorLevel=2}, Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}
```

Actually ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer() only returns parent ItemsControl for actual item containers. In your case ContentPresenter is the container type as you use simple ItemsControl. However as you incapsulate your  in a ContentControl in your data template it is important to specify AncestorLevel=2 as well.

Comment: ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer still fails in this case (returns null). "item" (in the value converter) is coming through as a ContentControl though.

Comment: Oups my bad Ancestor type should be ContentPresenter and AncestorLevel=2 is needed as well. Because your <local:FActionInfoControl/> is incapsulated in an additional ContentControl.

Comment: FYI for other WPF noobs out there: it turned out that <ContentControl> was just some legacy stuff. I removed that, and removed AncestorLevel=2 from the binding, and it continued to work. I imagine this might be a more common scenario for people.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing **`local:FActionInfoControl`** to converter, which is not a container for ItemsControl. You need to **pass container i.e. `ContentPresenter` which you can get using FindAncestor**.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                               AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=2},
                      Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}"
             Value="True">
 .....
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like ListBoxItem exists on ItemsControl. The Converter is never called with this as a result.

Comment: Oh yes I overlooked, you are using ItemsControl. For that you have to use ContentPresenter. Update the answer. See if that works.

Comment: Yah, it looks like you and @Didier came up with a similar answer. However, as he mentions "AncestorLevel=2" is required as well. Thanks for the help though!!